# Can't apply margin-top to some items while being able to apply margin-bottom to every item

Tags: html, css

I have a grid of items and I'm looking to add two Titles (i.e. class="work-category"), first at the beginning of the grid, and second, in the middle of the grid.

I'd like to add margin-top and margin-bottom to both Titles. However, while I can apply margin-bottom to both Titles, I CANNOT add margin-top to the second Title. I CAN add margin-top to the first Title.

See the image for clear demonstrations of the issue:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPS2D.png)

I'd like to add margin-top to the second Title, as well. How to fix this problem?

```css
.portfolio {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.container {
  width: 1170px;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.work-category {
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.portfolio .one-col {
  padding: 0px 30px;
}

.col-md-4 {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.footer {
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 104px;
  margin-top: -27px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="work-category">Title 1</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 one-col">...</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 one-col">...</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 one-col">...</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 one-col">...</div>
      <div class="work-category">Title 2</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 one-col">...</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 one-col">...</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 one-col">...</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 one-col">...</div>
      <div class="footer">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your snippet, there is no `margin-top` on any of the titles. The reason why your `margin-top` is not being applied is simply because Bootstrap uses a more specific selector:

```css
.row > * {
    margin-top: var(--bs-gutter-y);
}
```

Where the value is a Bootstrap CSS-variable. This selector means that any direct child of `.row` will have this `margin-top`-value applied from the CSS-variable. So all you need to do is use a more specific selector, such as:

```css
.row .work-category {
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

More on CSS-specificity from MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Full snippet:

```css
.portfolio {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.container {
  width: 1170px;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.row .work-category {
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.portfolio .one-col {
  padding: 0px 30px;
}

.col-md-4 {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.footer {
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 104px;
  margin-top: -27px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="work-category">Title 1</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 one-col">column</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 one-col">column</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 one-col">column</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 one-col">column</div>
      <div class="work-category">Title 2</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 one-col">column</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 one-col">column</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 one-col">column</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 one-col">column</div>
      <div class="footer">footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey it looks like that's not the problem. i tried the solution, but that didn't work. Also, previously, margin-bottom WAS indeed applied to both titles. I know this b/c I used developer Inspect tool on chrome to update margin-bottom values and the changes were reflected

Comment: I've also added font-family and font size values to .work-category (without the preceding .row) and they all are applied correctly.

Comment: **For your first comment:** I'm only going by what your code snippet is showing. I can't identify and find a solution to any problems if they aren't present in your code snippet. **For your second comment:** That's because Bootstrap isn't applying any font-styling.

Comment: What is so odd is that margin-bottom is applied OK but margin-bottom isn't.   Any idea what could potentially be the cause?     btw.  re: second comment, I meant that font-styling are applied OK

Comment: @roarsandmeows can you check your devtools and see if the CSS-styles are being loaded but not applied? like this: https://gyazo.com/d6b71ff3b8a20a3c0491a71e03f7707e